# Merge multi-line cell in double quotes

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have this tsv (tab separated) file having 2 columns.
The first column is a single (or group of) words and second column is it's meaning.

**test file**

```
test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge 
or skill in something."
testing examine
```

I am trying to merge second and third line because it is in double quotes. For e.g.

**Expected Output**

```
test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge or skill in something."
testing examine
```

I tried this:

```
awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $2}' test.tsv
test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge
or skill in something."
testing examine
```

But it does not merge the line 2 and 3. I tried "partsplit" and that merged all lines together.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t"}
{
    if (patsplit($0,a,/"[^"]+"/,s)) {
        gsub(/\n/,"",a[1])
        printf "%s%s%s", s[0],a[1],s[1]
    }
    else
        printf "%s", $0
    printf ";"
}' test.tsv
```

I need to keep the tab separated format like the original file. The only change required is to merge text in 2 double quotes.

Comment: I checked similar questions. The answers are very complicated. I am surprised to know that there is no simple, one liner answer for this trivial task.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What was wrong with the OP's use of the `regex` tag that prompted you to remove it with your edit? The OP uses regex is his attempted solution, and the nature of the question also warrants use of regex. The question was tagged correctly IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just replace each newline within quoted fields with a blank character, using GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `RT`:

```
$ awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/\n/," ",RT); ORS=RT} 1' file
test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge or skill in something."
testing examine
```

The above will work  no matter where the double quotes appear in your input, even if your quoted string includes double quotes that have been escaped by putting a second double quote next to them as is common in quoted fields in CSVs, TSVs, etc., e.g.:

```
$ cat file
test    try
test    a short exam to measure somebody's "knowledge
or skill" in something.
testing examine

test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's ""knowledge""
or skill in something."
testing examine
```

```
$ awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/\n/," ",RT); ORS=RT} 1' file
test    try
test    a short exam to measure somebody's "knowledge or skill" in something.
testing examine

test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's ""knowledge"" or skill in something."
testing examine
```

See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more info on parsing CSVs (which can also be applied to TSVs) with awk.

In response to the comments below - the awk command is doing exactly 1 thing every time - replacing each `\n` with a blank, that's what `gsub(/\n/," ",...)` does. If that's not what you want then just don't do that, do whatever you want to do instead, but you never said in your question how you want to merge the lines so I had to guess at something.

I'd recommend you don't just remove newlines as the other solutions do as that will concatenate words if there ever aren't spaces around the `\n`s but maybe you want `gsub(/[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*/," ",...)` or similar, I don't know.

Here's some other input to consider:

```
$ cat file
test    new first
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge
or skill in something."
testing examine

test    new second
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge
        or skill in something."
testing examine
```

The first one "new first" does not have a blank at the end of the line after `knowledge` and the second one "new second" has a tab at the start of the line before `or`. Now let's put all of the above test cases into one file (long spaces are tabs):

```
$ cat file
test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge
or skill in something."
testing examine

test    try
test    a short exam to measure somebody's "knowledge
or skill" in something.
testing examine

test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's ""knowledge""
or skill in something."
testing examine

test    new first
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge
or skill in something."
testing examine

test    new second
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge
        or skill in something."
testing examine
```

and then test that with all of the current answers:

1. Mine tweaked to use `gsub(/[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*/," ",...)` instead of `gsub(/\n/," ",...)`:

```
$ awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*/," ",RT); ORS=RT} 1' file
test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge or skill in something."
testing examine

test    try
test    a short exam to measure somebody's "knowledge or skill" in something.
testing examine

test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's ""knowledge"" or skill in something."
testing examine

test    new first
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge or skill in something."
testing examine

test    new second
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge or skill in something."
testing examine
```

2. [@potong's sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77623767/1745001):

```
$ sed ':a;N;/\n[^\t]*$/s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge or skill in something."testing examine
test    try
test    a short exam to measure somebody's "knowledgeor skill" in something.testing examine
test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's ""knowledge""or skill in something."testing examinetest    new firsttest    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledgeor skill in something."testing examinetest    new secondtest    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge
        or skill in something."testing examine
```

3. [@blhsing's awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77610930/1745001):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$2~/^"/{ORS=""}/"$/{ORS="\n"}1' file
test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge or skill in something."
testing examine

test    try
test    a short exam to measure somebody's "knowledge
or skill" in something.
testing examine

test    try
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's ""knowledge""
or skill in something."
testing examine

test    new first
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge
or skill in something."
testing examine

test    new second
test    "a short exam to measure somebody's knowledge
        or skill in something."
testing examine
```

so you can decide which is producing the behavior you want.

Comment: Very nice answer sir, thanks for sharing 

Comment: I agree with RavinderSingh13 comment. This is better than blhsing because it handles double quotes within double quotes elegantly. (suitable in my case). Upvoted and accepted. But I still think there should have been a generic solution built-in.

Comment: In some cases, the awk command is adding an extra space at the time of merging the second line. For e.g. https://gist.github.com/shantanuo/dfa74dcb323a20e9973d2ef6482ddc8a
sed does not add that extra space therefore I accepted that answer.

Comment: @shantanuo the awk command is doing exactly 1 thing every time - replacing each `\n` with a blank, that's what `gsub(/\n/," ",...)` does, as you never said how you wanted the lines merged so we all guessed. I'd have expected that to be a trivial thing for you to tweak if it wasn't exactly what you wanted but, anyway, I updated my answer to show an alternative that may be what you want to do instead, idk.

Comment: By the way regarding "I still think there should have been a generic solution built-in." - the awk language is built on the idea that you shouldn't introduce language constructs to do things that are easy to do with existing language constructs which is why the awk language is so tiny yet powerful. As you can see, this is yet another a case where it's trivial to do what you want with existing constructs.

Comment: If you want a tool with a million constructs to do everything as briefly as possible, though, there is another tool for that - https://www.zoitz.com/archives/13 :-).

Comment: Now it's 100% correct. accepted the answer. Previous command added an extra space awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/\n/," ",RT); ORS=RT} 1' file

Comment: I was afraid to post this question because I thought it is so trivial that the community will downvote and moderators will close it. what we think "trivial" is not always so.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the output record separator to an empty string when the second field begins with a double quote, and set it to a newline again when the record ends with a double quote:

```
awk -F'\t' '$2~/^"/{ORS=""}/"$/{ORS="\n"}1'
```

Demo: https://awk.js.org/?snippet=nEx499

To generalize this so that all multi-line columns enclosed in double quotes can be merged, you can set the output separator to an empty string upon an unterminated double quoted string, and set it to a newline again upon a
terminating double quote:

```
awk '/"($|\t)/{ORS="\n"}/(^|\t)"[^\t"]*$/{ORS=""}1'
```

Demo: https://awk.js.org/?snippet=LzpEGA

Comment: Can I use this for other files? For e.g. I have another file having 3 columns. Second or Third column (or both) can be multiline.

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly then.

Comment: This is correct. Thank you. Just for the sake of completeness, will it work if first column is multi-line?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, please see the second demo where I already made one of the values of the first column multi-line.

Comment: This does not seem to work with unicode characters. May be I have to upgrade my version of awk.

Comment: You should. awk did not get Unicode support until [recently](https://www.theregister.com/2022/08/23/universal_unix_tool_awk_gets/). gawk on the other hand has [supported](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bytes-vs_002e-Characters.html) Unicode for a while.

Comment: Not able to install. I tried a2p to convert the code to perl, but got the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried using gawk and setting the environment variable `LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF-8`?

Comment: Yes. Same results.

Comment: Can you share a piece of sample Unicode input that would reproduce the problem?

Comment: I tested the first 1000 lines of your given file in replit with gawk and the output looks as expected to me (demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/RegularRoughShareware ). So exactly which part of the input are you having a problem with in your environment, what's the output you're getting for that part of the input?

Comment: It is now working correctly. The problem was that the file was created on windows. Once I used dos2unix command it worked. Upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n[^\t]*$/s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

If a second line of a two line window does not contain a tab character, remove the newline between the first and second lines and go again.

Otherwise, print/delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: This solution will not work if there is a line break in the first column itself. Fortunately my data file has line breaks in the last column!